# magento 2 accessing foreach variable outside loop

Tags: magento2

Hi I have got the product collection here but am trying to push $sku value in $item, but seems like its not working, anything wrong am doing, please help

```
$items = array(); // trying to push sku data in this array
foreach($productCollection as $productCust){
 $sku = $productCust->getSku();// this is working fine
 array_push($items, $productCust->getSku());
}
```

**Update**

```
$items = [];
$productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$Test = $productCollection->getItems();
foreach($Test as $productCust){
 $sku = $productCust->getSku();// this is working fine
 $items[] = $sku;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = [];
$products = $productCollection->getItems();
foreach($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $items[] =  $sku;
}
```

Comment: not working bro, check the update code i have pasted after using you ans as a reference

Comment: Hi, I suggest using a debugger such as xdebug to step through your code. Or add loggers (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/log/log-magento.html) to your code. If not, at least try doing a plain `var_dump` on your `$items` Pretty sure there's a typo somewhere or you are trying to view some other piece of code/variable.

Comment: i have used logger, but removed that before posting the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = [];
$productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$products = $productCollection->getItems();
foreach($products as $product){
 $sku = $product->getSku();
 $items[] = $sku;
}
```